# Using theano compiled function with scipy minimize

Tags: python, optimization, theano, minimize

I'm currently writing a script to compute some functions that should fit some neutron scattering data.
I have an array X with the energy values which I pass to the function with other arguments to get the fitted curve.
I'm using a simple squared distance for minimization and I'd like to use theano and compute big arrays containing all the dataset at once (same parameter values for all the scattering angles measured, for now I'm just testing the minimize routine on each angle).

It's working fine with expression defined directly using standard library but using theano, the parameters of the 'x' vector from scipy's minimize are never updated, they just stayed the same as the initial guess just like if the cost function didn't depend on it.

Here's the code:

```
def resFunc_pseudo_voigt():
''' Resolution function for the backscattering spectrometer using a pseudo-voigt profile.

    Returns: The compiled theano function

    Inputs: normF   - scale factor which can be used for normalization
            S       - contribution factor for the lorentzian
            lorW    - lorentzian width
            gauW    - gaussian width    
            shift   - shift from 0 of the voigt profile's maximum
            bkgd    - background term

    Output: The compiled theano function result '''


X = T.vector()
normF = T.scalar()
S = T.scalar()
lorW = T.scalar()
gauW = T.scalar()
shift = T.scalar()
bkgd = T.scalar()


results, updates = theano.scan(lambda x_i: (normF * (S * lorW / (lorW**2 + (x_i - shift)**2) / np.pi 
                                         + (1-S) * T.exp(-(x_i-shift)**2 / 2*gauW**2) / gauW*T.sqrt(2*np.pi)
                                         + bkgd)), 
                                         sequences=X)

f_out = theano.function(inputs=[X, normF, S, lorW, gauW, shift, bkgd],
                    outputs=results, updates=updates, allow_input_downcast=True)


return f_out
```

And the use of minimize:

```
def res_cost(self, x, datas):

    cost = np.sum((datas.intensities - self.resFunc(datas.energies, *x))**2 / datas.errors**2)

    return cost


def resFit(self):

    for i, resFile in enumerate(self.dataList):
        resList = []
        for j, datas in enumerate(resFile):
            resList.append(optimize.minimize(lambda x: self.res_cost(x, datas),
                                             datas.intensities
                                             [50, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0, 0.05],
                                             bounds=[(0., 1000.), (0., 1.), (0., 10.), (0., 10.),
                                                     (-5., 5.), (0., 0.8)]))

            print('\n> Final result for qVal = %s: ' % datas.qVal, flush=True)
            print('Fit normF : ' + str(resList[j].x[0]), flush=True)
            print('Fit S     : ' + str(resList[j].x[1]), flush=True)
            print('Fit lorW  : ' + str(resList[j].x[2]), flush=True)
            print('Fit gauW  : ' + str(resList[j].x[3]), flush=True)
            print('Fit shift : ' + str(resList[j].x[4]), flush=True)
            print('Fit bkgd  : ' + str(resList[j].x[5]), flush=True)

        self.resFitList.append(resList)
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks